# mysql like query not working on browser

Tags: php, mysql

I  have below query  which works fine when given the exact column value but when used like operator it can't fetch any rows . how to pass % sign on the below query

```
$RegistrationMark = $_GET['RegistrationMark'];

$qr= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `EarlsdonMSIN_anpr_vega` where `RegistrationMark` like '" %.$RegistrationMark. %"'");
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: The `%` is part of your query string, so it needs to be within the `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your % marks are in the wrong place...

```
$qr= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `EarlsdonMSIN_anpr_vega` where `RegistrationMark` like '%" .$RegistrationMark. "%'");
```

You should be careful with using concatenated strings and SQL injection hacks.